# 16.04 install hung up

Tags: 16.04

I downloaded 16.04 last night and then started the install.  I got a message that said this install could take several hours, so I went to bed.  This am the install is hung up at Unpacking cabextract (i386) and a terminal screen within the install window is apparently asking me to OK a TrueType core font End User License Agreement (EULA) but, I can get no response from the screen, though my old 14.04 system seems to be working ok.  I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu so forgive me if I seem a bit dense.

Comment: Hello! First of all, I frankly don't understand the reason for down voting this question. The OP is a beginner and, like everyone else, he makes mistakes . Human nature, nothing new! AskUbuntu is for helping, not discouraging newbies. Now, back to the point: @sodypop, this was your mistake, that you went to bed during the installation process instead of staying close by, ready to react whenever your PC asks you for. Installing an OS is like assisting a newborn coming into the earth. There are always little things to take care of. This is a general advice, not a real answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you haven't been hung up for 6 hours...

I had read that during Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade you need to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to access hidden accept buttons to accept the `EULA` (End User License Agreement) for the MS TrueType Fonts. I guess this issue has been around for awhile as these user discuss in May 2014 on the  Ubuntu Forums: [EULA Tab Key](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223330)

When I upgraded I chose not to install 3rd party stuff to save time so I didn't see the screen and I can't describe it in detail.